SQL Join Over Non-Unique Data - Windowing/Over/Order By/Distinct
I've lurked long enough to know you folks will nail this, please pardon noobness:
Given some sample data:
Table JOBS



JOBNAME
JOBCOUNT
STEPTOTAL
STRTDATE
STRTTIME




MIS_JOB_1
23013400
15
20240429
230142


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
15
20240903
230137



Table JOBSTEPS



JOBNAME
JOBCOUNT
STEPCOUNT
SDLDATE
SDLTIME




MIS_JOB_1
23013400
1
20240429
230142


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
2
20240429
230143


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
3
20240429
230143


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
4
20240429
230144


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
20240429
230145


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
6
20240429
230146


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
7
20240429
230147


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
8
20240429
230147


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
9
20240429
230148


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
10
20240429
230149


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
11
20240429
230150


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
12
20240429
230150


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
13
20240429
230151


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
14
20240429
230152


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
15
20240429
230153


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
1
20240903
230137


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
2
20240903
230138


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
3
20240903
230139


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
4
20240903
230140


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
20240903
230140


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
6
20240903
230141


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
7
20240903
230142


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
8
20240903
230143


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
9
20240903
230144


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
10
20240903
230145


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
11
20240903
230146


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
12
20240903
230147


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
13
20240903
230148


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
14
20240903
230148


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
15
20240903
230149



select
a.JOBNAME,
a.JOBCOUNT,
a.STEPTOTAL,
b.STEPCOUNT,
b.PROGNAME,
b.EXTCMD,
b.SDLDATE,
b.SDLTIME,
a.SDLUNAME,
a.STRTDATE,
a.STRTTIME
from JOBS a inner join JOBSTEPS b on a.JOBNAME = b.JOBNAME and a.JOBCOUNT = b.JOBCOUNT where b.SDLDATE = a.STRTDATE

Need better join to perhaps involve a.STRTDATE, b.SDLDATE, a.STEPTOTAL, b.STEPCOUNT

b.SDLDATE can be greater if steps run long
a.STEPTOTAL is the highest b.STEPCOUNT
without joining to later JOBNAME, JOBCOUNT data which is non-unique over time

I have tried joins like above by pushing SDLDATE out: however there are cases when JOBNAME, JOBCOUNT can be re-used again the next day - and other cases when SDLDATE for a given set of JOBSTEPS can span several days.  So I either lose data or join too much to earlier JOBS records.

Please show the expected result, ask a clear question and explain what exactly goes wrong with your query. "Better" and "Perhaps" is too vague, we can't work with that.

Why are there separate columns for date and time?

Is there an actual question here?

Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: a clear question/problem that you are trying to solve; the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (that we can copy-paste and execute); the details of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment the post has a large amount of data (in a not easily usable format) and some code but no explanation of what problem you are trying to solve or what you expect the solution to be which makes the question difficult (impossible?) to answer.

If you are having problems with jobs spanning two-or-more days or repeating in consecutive days then give sample data that demonstrates that problem - at the moment your sample data has jobs that start and end on the same day and do not repeat. Also, consider making your [MRE] actually be minimal - do you really need 15 steps to demonstrate the problem? Could you simplify the problem to 3 or 5 steps?

Provided you do not have overlapping sequences of steps, from Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern patching to find the steps within a sequence and set the start date for each set of steps (even if there are multiple on the same day or if they go over multiple days). Once you have found that then you can use it to join the two tables:
SELECT j.*,
       MAX(s.sdldate) OVER (PARTITION BY s.jobname, s.jobcount, s.match) AS enddate,
       s.stepcount,
       s.sdldate
FROM   jobsteps
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY jobname, jobcount
         ORDER BY sdldate
         MEASURES
           step_one.sdldate AS strtdate,
           match_number()   AS match
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( step_one next_step* )
         DEFINE
           step_one AS stepcount = 1,
           next_step AS stepcount = PREV(stepcount) + 1
       ) s
       INNER JOIN jobs j
       ON (   j.jobname   = s.jobname
          AND j.jobcount  = s.jobcount
          AND j.strtdate  = s.strtdate
          )
ORDER BY
       j.jobname, j.jobcount, s.sdldate

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE jobs (jobname, jobcount, steptotal, strtdate) AS
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400, 5, DATE '2024-04-29' + INTERVAL '23:01:42' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400, 5, DATE '2024-09-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400, 3, DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '01:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE jobsteps (jobname, jobcount, stepcount, sdldate) AS
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  1,  DATE '2024-04-29' + INTERVAL '23:01:42' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  2,  DATE '2024-04-29' + INTERVAL '23:01:43' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  3,  DATE '2024-04-29' + INTERVAL '23:01:43' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  4,  DATE '2024-04-29' + INTERVAL '23:01:44' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  5,  DATE '2024-04-29' + INTERVAL '23:01:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  1,  DATE '2024-09-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  2,  DATE '2024-09-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  3,  DATE '2024-09-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  4,  DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  5,  DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  1,  DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '01:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  2,  DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '01:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MIS_JOB_1', 23013400,  3,  DATE '2024-09-04' + INTERVAL '01:00:02' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL

Note: A DATE data-type has both date and time components. Don't store dates and times in separate columns (and especially not as strings), instead use a single DATE column containing both components. If you must store the components as two columns (please don't) then use TO_DATE(date_column || time_column, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') to convert them to a date and then use the query above).
Outputs:



JOBNAME
JOBCOUNT
STEPTOTAL
STRTDATE
ENDDATE
STEPCOUNT
SDLDATE




MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-04-29 23:01:42
2024-04-29 23:01:45
1
2024-04-29 23:01:42


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-04-29 23:01:42
2024-04-29 23:01:45
2
2024-04-29 23:01:43


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-04-29 23:01:42
2024-04-29 23:01:45
3
2024-04-29 23:01:43


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-04-29 23:01:42
2024-04-29 23:01:45
4
2024-04-29 23:01:44


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-04-29 23:01:42
2024-04-29 23:01:45
5
2024-04-29 23:01:45


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-09-03 23:59:58
2024-09-04 00:00:01
1
2024-09-03 23:59:58


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-09-03 23:59:58
2024-09-04 00:00:01
2
2024-09-03 23:59:59


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-09-03 23:59:58
2024-09-04 00:00:01
3
2024-09-03 23:59:59


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-09-03 23:59:58
2024-09-04 00:00:01
4
2024-09-04 00:00:00


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
5
2024-09-03 23:59:58
2024-09-04 00:00:01
5
2024-09-04 00:00:01


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
3
2024-09-04 01:00:00
2024-09-04 01:00:02
1
2024-09-04 01:00:00


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
3
2024-09-04 01:00:00
2024-09-04 01:00:02
2
2024-09-04 01:00:01


MIS_JOB_1
23013400
3
2024-09-04 01:00:00
2024-09-04 01:00:02
3
2024-09-04 01:00:02



fiddle

It's not clear what it is about and what is the question, but it looks like some jobs scheduling and logging (could SDL be StepsDataLog).
First a blind guess of your code attempt that should get you all the jobs data and job steps logged.
Select     j.JOBNAME, j.JOBCOUNT, j.STEPTOTAL,
           js.STEPCOUNT, js.SDLDATE, js.SDLTIME,
           j.STRTDATE, j.STRTTIME
From       jobs j
Left Join  jobsteps js ON(js.JOBNAME = j.JOBNAME And js.SDLDATE = j.STRTDATE)
Order By   j.JOBNAME, j.STRTDATE, js.STEPCOUNT

/*      R e s u l t : 
JOBNAME     JOBCOUNT  STEPTOTAL  STEPCOUNT  SDLDATE   SDLTIME   STRTDATE    STRTTIME
----------  --------  ---------  ---------  --------  --------  ----------  --------- 
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          1  20240429  230142    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          2  20240429  230143    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          3  20240429  230143    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          4  20240429  230144    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          5  20240429  230145    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          6  20240429  230146    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          7  20240429  230147    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          8  20240429  230147    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          9  20240429  230148    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         10  20240429  230149    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         11  20240429  230150    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         12  20240429  230150    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         13  20240429  230151    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         14  20240429  230152    20240429    230142
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         15  20240429  230153    20240429    230142
--
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          1  20240903  230137    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          2  20240903  230138    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          3  20240903  230139    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          4  20240903  230140    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          5  20240903  230140    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          6  20240903  230141    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          7  20240903  230142    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          8  20240903  230143    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15          9  20240903  230144    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         10  20240903  230145    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         11  20240903  230146    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         12  20240903  230147    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         13  20240903  230148    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         14  20240903  230148    20240903    230137
MIS_JOB_1   23013400         15         15  20240903  230149    20240903    230137      */

Next, some possibly usefull info that could be taken out of the data. Using strings when dealing with dates is not a good idea. Problems with spaning over to next day just make it more complicated. Below code converts your strings into DATE datatype to get the corect time span in seconds between first and last job's step logged.
Select     j.JOBCOUNT, j.JOBNAME, j.STEPTOTAL,    
           To_Char( To_Date(j.STRTDATE || ' ' || j.STRTTIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24miss') , 
                    'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "STARTED_AT", 
            Count(js.STEPCOUNT) "COUNT_STEPS_LOGGED",
            To_Char(Min( To_Date(js.SDLDATE || ' ' || js.SDLTIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24miss') ), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "FIRST_STEP_AT",
            To_Char(Max( To_Date(js.SDLDATE || ' ' || js.SDLTIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24miss') ), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "LAST_STEP_AT",
    ROUND(   
           ( Max( To_Date(js.SDLDATE || ' ' || js.SDLTIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24miss') ) - 
             Min( To_Date(js.SDLDATE || ' ' || js.SDLTIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24miss') ) )
             * ( 24 * 60 * 60 ), 0
         ) "SECONDS_FIRST_TO_LAST"
From       jobs j
Left Join  jobsteps js ON(js.JOBNAME = j.JOBNAME And 
                          js.JOBCOUNT = j.JOBCOUNT And
                          js.SDLDATE = j.STRTDATE)
Group By   j.JOBCOUNT, j.JOBNAME, j.STEPTOTAL, 
           To_Char( To_Date(j.STRTDATE || ' ' || j.STRTTIME, 'yyyymmdd hh24miss') , 
                    'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

/*      R e s u l t : 
  JOBCOUNT  JOBNAME     STEPTOTAL  STARTED_AT           COUNT_STEPS_LOGGED  FIRST_STEP_AT        LAST_STEP_AT         SECONDS_FIRST_TO_LAST
----------  ----------  ---------  -------------------  ------------------  -------------------  -------------------  ---------------------
  23013400  MIS_JOB_1          15  29.04.2024 23:01:42                  15  29.04.2024 23:01:42  29.04.2024 23:01:53                     11
  23013400  MIS_JOB_1          15  03.09.2024 23:01:37                  15  03.09.2024 23:01:37  03.09.2024 23:01:49                     12      */

Seee the fiddle here.

The OP states "other cases when SDLDATE for a given set of JOBSTEPS can span several days". Joining on the date component will not work when the steps span multiple days.
